# Codificar variables

Tags: r

Supongamos que tengo dos df:

**DF1:**

```
Id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Codigo <- c(3,1,1,5,4)
df1 <- data.frame(Id, Codigo)
df1
```

> ```
>  Id   Codigo
>   1      3
>   2      1
>   3      1
>   4      5
>   5      4
> ```

**DF2:**

```
Id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Codigo <- c("Fresas","Limones","Sandias","Tomates","Manzanas")
df2 <- data.frame(Id, Codigo)
df2
```

> Id Codigo
> 1  Fresas
> 2  Limones
> 3  Sandias
> 4  Tomates
> 5  Manzanas

Quiero codificar el df1 por el código del df2:

```
codificacion <- car::recode(df1$Codigo,
                       "
                       1='Fresas';
                       2='Limones';
                       3='Sandias';
                       4='Tomates';
                       5='Manzanas'
                       ")

df1$Codigo <- codificacion
df1
```

> Id  Codigo
> 1   Sandias
> 2   Fresas
> 3   Fresas
> 4   Manzanas
> 5   Tomates

Ahora en vez de 5 códigos tengo 5.000. ¿Cómo hago para no tener que meter la
parte de recode a mano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x="Codigo", by.y="Id", all.x = TRUE, sort=FALSE)

  Codigo Id Codigo.y
1      3  1  Sandias
2      1  2   Fresas
3      1  3   Fresas
4      5  4 Manzanas
5      4  5  Tomates
```

Es un equivalente al `left join` de sql, se recuperan todas las filas del `df1` y las coincidentes de `df2` por la relación entre `Código == Id`

Pero más fácil aún es convertir la columna `df1$Codigo` en un factor configurado por los valores en `df2`

```
df1$Codigo = factor(df1$Codigo, levels = df2$Id, labels = df2$Codigo)

  Id   Codigo
1  1  Sandias
2  2   Fresas
3  3   Fresas
4  4 Manzanas
5  5  Tomates
```